# how to use if condition in .map function?

Tags: react-native

**Hi,  I used if condition like below,  but  there is nothing rendering on the screen. By the way, there is 'MAVI' in leader array**

```
renderall() {           
  return this.state.leader.map(alb =>  {
    if(alb.Renk == 'MAVI') { 
        <View style={styles.container} key={counter = counter + 1}> 
          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.Tescil_No}  </Text>

          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'6%'}]}> {alb.GumrukAdi}  </Text>

          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.ACIKLAMA}   </Text>                                                
        </View>
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement in your map

Comment: Hi andrew again you :) , but here is return below renderall()  ?

Comment: You need the first `return` to return the array of mapped items, you need a return in the `.map` otherwise nothing is getting mapped, you will just end up with an array of undefined items. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a return in your `.map`. Notice that inside the `if statement` I am returning the items being mapped.

```
renderall() {           
  return this.state.leader.map(alb =>  {
    if(alb.Renk == 'MAVI') {
      return (    
        <View style={styles.container} key={counter = counter + 1}> 
          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.Tescil_No}  </Text>

          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {marginLeft:'6%'}]}> {alb.GumrukAdi}  </Text>

          <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { marginLeft:'5%'}]}> {alb.ACIKLAMA}   </Text>                                                
          </View>
      );
    }
  });
}
```

This article explains in more detail how the `.map` function works 
https://codeburst.io/learn-understand-javascripts-map-function-ffc059264783

Here is a very small example showing how to use the `.map` function. Notice the return statement.

```js
let leaders = ['Tom','Jerry','Mike'];

let mappedLeaders = leaders.map((leader, index) => {
  return `${leader} is number ${index}`; // notice that I am returning here
})

console.log(mappedLeaders)
```

Here is an example of using a `.map` with an `if statement` inside it. Notice we will get `undefined` for the first item in the `mappedLeaders` as we are not returning anything for the first item because **Tom** is excluded due to the fact that his name is too short.

```js
let leaders = ['Tom','Jerry','Mike'];

let mappedLeaders = leaders.map((leader, index) => {
  if (leader.length > 3) {
    return `${leader} is number ${index}`; // notice that I am returning here
  }
});

console.log(mappedLeaders)
```